# Configured values different to Running values, even after full restart

Tags: sql-server, filestream, sql-server-2012

I am trying to change the **FILESTREAM Access Level** property on a SQL Server Express database. The **Configured values** section of the **Advanced** tab of my Server Properties dialogue box looks like so:

[image: Server Properties - Configured]

The **Running values** section looks like this:

[image: Server Properties - Running]

This is before and after a full restart of the computer. Am I right in thinking that SQL Server Express just doesn't support this option, or could there be another reason this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Jakub Hromadík](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/123303/jakub-hromad%C3%ADk) originally wrote in a comment:

> This just happened to me. No matter what I did, the running value was always Disabled. What finally did it for me was repairing the SQL Server installation. I'm running SQL Server 2016 SP1

This also worked for me.

Note also:

From the documentation, [filestream access level Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/filestream-access-level-server-configuration-option)

> Before this option has any effect, the Windows administration settings for FILESTREAM must be enabled

and be sure to follow all the steps in [How to: Enable FILESTREAM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923(v=sql.105).aspx)